# complexity of system of equations defining affine variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, affine-geometry

Say you have an affine variety $X$ in $n$-dimensional affine space. (You can even assume we are over $\mathbb{C}$, but I believe the nature of my question is algebraic).

I want to bound from above the complexity of a system of equations defining $X$. My guess is that the following parameters should be enough:

1. $n$ - dimension of ambient space.
2. $\mu$ - dimension of $X$
3. $d$ - degree of $X$ in say the standart projective compactification of 
   $\mathbb{A}^n$.

I don't mind what concept of complexity to take, say the max power in which any variable is taken from any equation.

Thank you very much!